# Using WhenEvent to change initial conditions of a system of Ode

Tags: differential-equations, event-detection

i want to solve a system of two differential equations and apply two conditions.
The first one is to stop the integration when the first condition (D1[s]==0,N1[s]==0) (in my code) is met.Lets say this happens at a value of s i name smax
Then i want to alter one initial condition and start the integration from the beginning start s=0 (not from the point smax that the last integration has ended).
This should go on for n times before the code stops.
What i expect to see plotting it is n different lines with similar behavior.
I hope this makes sense.
It might be quite simple but i can't seem to make it work.

```
\[CapitalGamma] = 5/3;
 c4 = 6;
 smax = 2;
 Rinit = 1.05;
 \[Gamma]1 = 0.8;
 \[Gamma]2 = 0.9;
 \[Gamma]uinit = (\[Gamma]1 + \[Gamma]2)/2;
{sol1, values} = 
 Reap@NDSolve[{D1[s] ==2 (-1 + R[s]) R[s] (-(-1 + \[CapitalGamma]) \[Gamma]u[s] + 
     c4 ((-1 + R[s]) R[s]^3)^((1 - \[CapitalGamma])/
      2) (-2 + \[CapitalGamma]) \[CapitalGamma] \[Gamma]u[s]^(2 - \[CapitalGamma]) + 
     c4 ((-1 + R[s]) R[s]^3)^((1 - \[CapitalGamma])/2) (-1 + \[CapitalGamma]) \[CapitalGamma] \[Gamma]u[
       s]^-\[CapitalGamma]), 
 N1[s] == -(1 + \[Gamma]u[s]^2) (1 - \[CapitalGamma] + 
     c4 (-1 + R[s])^(1/2 - \[CapitalGamma]/2)
       R[s]^(-(3/2) (-1 + \[CapitalGamma])) (2 +4 R[s] (-1 + \[CapitalGamma]) - 
        3 \[CapitalGamma]) \[CapitalGamma] \[Gamma]u[s]^(1 - \[CapitalGamma])), 
 R'[s] == D1[s]/Sqrt[D1[s]^2 + N1[s]^2], 
 Derivative[1][\[Gamma]u][s] == N1[s]/Sqrt[D1[s]^2 + N1[s]^2], 
 R[0] == Rinit, \[Gamma]u[0] == \[Gamma]uinit, 
 WhenEvent[ {D1[s] == 0, N1[s] == 0} , 
  Sow[{s, D1[s], N1[s], Abs[N1[s]/D1[s]]}]; smax = s; 
  If[Abs[N1[s]/D1[s]] > 1, {\[Gamma]uinit = \[Gamma]2, 
    Print[\[Gamma]uinit]}]; 
  If[Abs[N1[s]/D1[s]] < 1, {\[Gamma]uinit = \[Gamma]1, 
    Print[\[Gamma]uinit]}]]}, {R, \[Gamma]u}, {s, 0, smax}];

ParametricPlot[Evaluate[{R[s], \[Gamma]u[s]} /. sol1], {s, 0, smax}, 
 AspectRatio -> 1, PlotStyle -> ColorData["GreenPinkTones"], 
 AxesLabel -> {"R", "\[Gamma]u"}]
```

Comment: 'i want to alter one initial condition and start the integration from the beginning', how different is it from simply propagating n times, each time with different initial conditions. You can stop each propagation as desired using `WhenEvent`. Does it make sense?

Comment: It might be the same. I am not sure. How do i set the new initial condition? I want to set the new value depending on the result of the If command.

Comment: `smax = s;` causes Mathematica to hang as `NDSolve` terminates.  Delete it.  Also, `γuinit` is reset only to `γ1` or `γ2`, so there are only three distinct sets of initial conditions.  Finally, computing `Abs[N1[s]/D1[s]]` is dangerous, when `WhenEvent` is triggered by `D1[s] == 0`.  All that said, the computation is straightforward to perform, if I understand your goal correctly.